# gnome shell menu doesn't load on startup in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, gnome

I use Ubuntu 12.04. I recently tried to install gnome-shell-extensions-commons. After that I powered down my laptop. Now when I try to login to gnome-shell the menu and top panel do not show. I am not sure whether gnome-shell-extensions-commons is the one responsible for this.

**Update :** I tried to purge and re-install gnome-shell but still no change. Gnome-shell just doesn't load up. Also did autoremove before installing.

Answer (score 0):

All my extensions are disabled and I still have this problem after logging out and then in. I haven't, to my knowledge, changed any drivers. I have been able to go to the tty terminals and type 'gnome-shell --display :0' and that starts the shell. But is not a fix, sorry.